# Beginner Button click event

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android, i am writing a program where when a user clicks a button a `Alert Dialog` to appear. This alert dialog has 2 buttons, `Yes and No`. Upon clicking Yes/No, i need to `sysout` the response.

The code i have so far; Can someone help me add the Alert Dialog;

```
public class HelloWorldProjectActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myFirstScreen);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId()==(R.id.button1)){
        System.out.println("first button clicked");

         // I need a Alert Dialog to appear here, and that will have 2 buttons YES and NO, the users response should be printed to the console.

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot `System.out.print()`.

There are several methods to display the result. One is to use `Toast`. It will briefly show a text message and then disappear.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Are you sure?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(TestAndroidActivity.this, "YES CLICKED",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(TestAndroidActivity.this, "NO CLICKED",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).show();
```

Modify your code as follows:

- The activity class doesn't have to implement `OnClickListener`.

  - Thus, remove `onClick()` method
- Go to the layout file, add an attribute `android:onClick="click"` in the button declaration.

  - Add `public void click(View view)` with the previous code.

Comment: where should i enter the above code ? Inside the if condition ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there really isn't any system.out to print to in android. What you should try instead is printing to the log. For information on how to print to the log, check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) out. To then see the activity of the log (including messages you printed to it), checkout the [logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html).

Second, for information on creating an alert dialog, please [view this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog).

Comment: Actually, `System.out.println` works just fine in Android. It will also generate logs that appear when you use `adb logcat`.

Comment: Didn't you ever try it? .out is printed as "I/info" (green), and .err as a "W/warning" (orange)... It's funny that we always think that Log is the solution when System.* compiles just fine... so where does it go? Now you know. :-)